# Magento 2: How to Add Additional Countries?

Tags: magento2, custom, country-regions, additional-information

Apart from Magento Default Country list. I have below Countries which needs to be added.

```
MINE                     MAGENTO MAPPED
-------------------------------------------
Antigua and Barbuda => Antigua & Barbuda
Brunei Darussalam => Brunei
Cote D'Ivoire => Côte d’Ivoire
Hong Kong => Hong Kong SAR China
Iran (Islamic Republic of) => Iran
Macau => Macau SAR China
Myanmar => Myanmar (Burma)
Russian Federation => Russia
Saint Kitts and Nevis => St. Kitts & Nevis
Saint Lucia => St. Lucia
Slovakia (Slovak Republic) => Slovakia
Viet Nam => Vietnam
Virgin Islands (U.S.) => U.S. Virgin Islands
```

------------------- PENDING TO MAP ----------------------

```
Korea => PENDING North Korea, South Korea?
Lao Democratic Republic => PENDING Laos/Central African Republic/Dominican Republic?
Puerto Rico => PENDING
```

How to define that Code or get Standard Code for Countries from http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm?

So once it's added it will be displayed through Country DropDown.

May be Need to work with below tables

```
directory_country
directory_country_region
directory_country_region_name
```

Or

**vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\en.xml** file

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and it helps me to add a new country

[Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330838/add-new-nation-into-nations-list-in-magento-2-3-5/330897#330897)