# Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, country-regions

I want to add a new country `Northern Ireland` with the country code `XI` in Magento 2.3.5 Admin. any idea for this?

I already tried with this -

> [Add new country in default country dropdown in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317942/add-new-country-in-default-country-dropdown-in-magento-2-3-5)

I found the same answer everywhere but it does not work for me so please help me with this.

> if I want to update the data in "ICUDATA-region" so can it be
> possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a module

module registration file

**Vendor/NorthernIreland/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_NorthernIreland',
    __DIR__
);
```

module initialization file

**Vendor/NorthernIreland/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_NorthernIreland" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

file di, register plugin

**Vendor/NorthernIreland/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists">
        <plugin name="vendor_northernireland" type="Vendor\NorthernIreland\Plugin\Framework\Locale\TranslatedListsPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

plugin

**Vendor/NorthernIreland/Plugin/Framework/Locale/TranslatedListsPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\NorthernIreland\Plugin\Framework\Locale;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\ListsInterface;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
class TranslatedListsPlugin
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function aroundGetCountryTranslation(
        ListsInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        $value,
        $locale = null
    ) {
        if ($value == 'XI') {
            /* need to add $locale selector */
            return 'Northern Ireland';
        }
        return $proceed($value, $locale);
    }
}
```

db path, add code XI to directory_country table

**Vendor/NorthernIreland/Setup/Patch/Data/AddDataForNorthernIreland.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\NorthernIreland\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;

/**
 * Class AddDataForNorthernIreland
 */
class AddDataForNorthernIreland implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /**
         * Fill table directory/country
         */
        $data = [
            ['XI', 'XI', 'XI'] //iso3_code ???
        ];

        $columns = ['country_id', 'iso2_code', 'iso3_code'];
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertArray(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('directory_country'),
            $columns,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '2.0.0';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

then run console commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (optional)
```

check your system configuration (*Stores/Setting/Configuration/General/General/Country Options*), Northern Ireland should appear on all listings in this section.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check

Comment: I just want to know that do you know "icuDATA-region" and if I want to update the data in that so can it be possible?

Comment: sorry, now I don't know how you can change this

Comment: thanks, your solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@vitalii hi

$data = [['XI', 'XI', 'XII'],['ZB', 'ZB', 'ZBB'] ];

to add multiple countries we have to do something like this ??

I have created the same extension with the help of Magento link https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057988152-How-to-add-a-new-country-to-Magento-2-

but I have already added countries code to the table instead of creating patch

but in may case plugin giving error on return

```
    return $proceed($value, $locale);
```

this return syntax error as $value have not value why ?
please help me